# How does this CSS code apply a different horizontal color gradient to each line of text?

Tags: css

I found a jsfiddle that can applies a color gradient to specific lines of text. It applies a different 2 color gradient for each line of text. And it does a consistent pattern. Black to Red, Red to Black, Black to Blue, Blue to Black.

I have no idea how it works though. Can someone explain?

Here is the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/cers/o9s70yjq/2/

Here is the code

HTML

```
<p><em>Nobody is perfect.</em> At times we have difficulty managing our finances, we don’t always take our medications as planned, and sometimes we don’t perform up to par at work. However, research shows that people experience these problems to different degrees. Across financial strata, research reveals that the financially less well-off engage in these behaviors more often than those who are financially stable (1). These behaviors are particularly concerning, because, for those with limited financial resources, they can lead to poverty as well as perpetuate it.</p>

<p>In their article, “<a href="http://www.sciencemag.org/content/341/6149/976">Poverty Impedes Cognitive Function</a>,” which appears in the latest issue of Science, University of Warwick Professor Anandi Mani and several other social scientists (2) suggest poverty, and the ever-present concerns that come with it, places an undue burden on an individual’s limited mental resources. Compared with those who are free from poverty, this burden leaves those in poverty with fewer cognitive resources with which to make choices and take action. Mani et al. write, the poor “are less capable not because of inherent traits, but because the very context of poverty imposes load and impedes cognitive capacity.”</p>

<p>However, it is important to note that their explanation is not limited to the traditional populations of poverty, defined by a specific income level or ability to access basic human needs. The authors define poverty “broadly as the gap between one’s needs and the resources available to fulfill them.” That is, people in poverty are those who feel “poor,” who feel they have less than they need.</p>
```

And here is the CSS

````
p {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%00%02%00%00%00%3C%08%02%00%00%00%C3%A4%FC%AE%00%00%00%25IDAT%18%D3c```%F8%CF%C0%C0%C4%C0%C0%C0%40S%8A%E1%3F%ADm%80Y%04%B1%8D.%16%FD%A7%8B%8F%00e%B4%04m%18%DC%1D%8A%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB`%82) 0 0 / 100% 6em repeat-y;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

em {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-style: normal;
}

a {
  text-decoration-color: black;
}
````

Comment: Background-clip. They assign color to background and then use it as a color for text by `background-clip`

Comment: I am still wondering how the backgrounds are auto aligned with each line of text.

Comment: thanks! one more thing, what does "0 0 / 100% 6em repeat-y;" do in the code?

Comment: @PatrickJFitzgerald I've already explained it into comment under my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the tricks in this jsfiddle are :

First he set a [`background`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) to the `<p>` that mean the red and blue color are comming from the `background-image` property.

### [image]

Second he set the  [`background-clip CSS property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) to text that would appely the `background-image` only to the text in the `<p>` tag.

at last he The [`-webkit-text-fill-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color) and that property would make the text fill color transparent.

and the result is as below

````css
p {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%00%02%00%00%00%3C%08%02%00%00%00%C3%A4%FC%AE%00%00%00%25IDAT%18%D3c```%F8%CF%C0%C0%C4%C0%C0%C0%40S%8A%E1%3F%ADm%80Y%04%B1%8D.%16%FD%A7%8B%8F%00e%B4%04m%18%DC%1D%8A%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB`%82) 0 0 / 100% 6em repeat-y;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

em {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-style: normal;
}

a {
  text-decoration-color: black;
}
````

```html
<p><em>Nobody is perfect.</em> At times we have difficulty managing our finances, we don’t always take our medications as planned, and sometimes we don’t perform up to par at work. However, research shows that people experience these problems to different degrees. Across financial strata, research reveals that the financially less well-off engage in these behaviors more often than those who are financially stable (1). These behaviors are particularly concerning, because, for those with limited financial resources, they can lead to poverty as well as perpetuate it.</p>

<p>In their article, “<a href="http://www.sciencemag.org/content/341/6149/976">Poverty Impedes Cognitive Function</a>,” which appears in the latest issue of Science, University of Warwick Professor Anandi Mani and several other social scientists (2) suggest poverty, and the ever-present concerns that come with it, places an undue burden on an individual’s limited mental resources. Compared with those who are free from poverty, this burden leaves those in poverty with fewer cognitive resources with which to make choices and take action. Mani et al. write, the poor “are less capable not because of inherent traits, but because the very context of poverty imposes load and impedes cognitive capacity.”</p>

<p>However, it is important to note that their explanation is not limited to the traditional populations of poverty, defined by a specific income level or ability to access basic human needs. The authors define poverty “broadly as the gap between one’s needs and the resources available to fulfill them.” That is, people in poverty are those who feel “poor,” who feel they have less than they need.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how he made the background image align to each line of text, or how he was able to apply a different gradient to each line?

Comment: he used the     `background-size: 100% 6em;` the 6em define the backgound vertical size and the different gradient to each line are randomly, and give at an upvote or mark this as answred

Comment: thanks! one more thing, why was it typed out "0 0 / 100% 6em?", what does the "0 0 /" do? 

also, what does repeat-y; do? Repeat the image vertically?

Comment: those are  background position x & y
`background-image: url.....;
    background-position-x: 0px;
    background-position-y: 0px;
    background-size: 100% 6em;
    background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
    background-repeat-y: repeat;`
all the property used in background  , so mark it as answred and five it an upvote

Answer (score 0):

Things will became much more clear if you will remove `-webkit-background-clip` rule. This rule tells browser to only apply background definition to the pixels filled by rendered text instead of all pixels in the area. Here is how result looks like without this style:

[image: result without background clip]

Another trick is inlined background image that defines gradient itself. Here is it:

[image: background image]

If you will resize it - you will find very similar result:

[image: resized background]

Remaining styles defines background size so it will roughly cover whole paragraph

Comment: do you know how that image was produced from this? 

url(data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%00%02%00%00%00%3C%08%02%00%00%00%C3%A4%FC%AE%00%00%00%25IDAT%18%D3c```%F8%CF%C0%C0%C4%C0%C0%C0%40S%8A%E1%3F%ADm%80Y%04%B1%8D.%16%FD%A7%8B%8F%00e%B4%04m%18%DC%1D%8A%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB`%82) 0 0 / 100% 6em repeat-y;

what does the "0 0 / 100% 6em repeat-y;" do?

Comment: Also, how did he get the image to fit exactly behind the lines of text?

Comment: This is same image, it is just encoded as `data:` url. I've simply opened your jsfiddle in Firefox and clicked on image into dev.tools to open it in new tab. You can get binary version of it by something like this (php code): `urldecode(explode($image,',',2)[0])`

Comment: Image position is defined by remaining properties of `background` style. These `0 0 / 100% 6em` are actually shorthand for `background-position` and `background-size` respectively. So image is placed at top left corner of element and resized to fit 100% width and 6 lines of text. 6 lines, I guess, are required to let single line of image to roughly match text line size. `repeat-y` tells to repeat image vertically if defined size is not enough.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing. Why was it necessary to specify  line-height: 1.5em; . When I removed this line, I noticed that the picture became out of alignment with the lines.

Comment: It is simple: height of one line of the background with given `background-size` values is `24px`. Default font size (that is not specified) in browser is `16px`. Hence to have lines of text to match lines of background we need to have `line-height` to be `24px` or (taking in mind default font size) - `24/16=1.5em`

Answer (score 0):

The `background:url(...)` is setting the image that has the gradient.You can also achieve something like that with `background:linear-gradient`.

The `-webkit-background-clip: text` is specifying how far the background should extend within an element.

The  `-webkit-text-fill-color:transparent` specifies the fill color of characters of text.

Comment: Thanks! do you know what "0 0 / 100% 6em repeat-y;" of the code does?

Comment: Although it is already answered, `background` is the short way to write all properties for a background. So `0 0` is short for `background-postition: 0 0`, `100% 6em` is short for `background-size:100% 6em`, `repeat-y` is short for `background-repeat:repeat-y`. You can find all these properties in great detail [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) .